# C# show/hide dynamic created button from dynamic created button

Tags: c#, button, programmatically-created

I have a simple C# Windows Form Application, where i create two set of buttons based on a specific loop. first set (called contractButton) are visible but the next set created beside them (called infoButton) is hidden. What I would like to achieve is bu clicking on contractButton to set visible to true for the corresponding infoButton generated beside him.
Here is the code I have,

```
namespace DynamicButtons
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) //simple loop just to simulate the request
            {
                createContractButton();  //will generate 3 contractButtons with Visible = true
                createInfoButton();  //will cgenerate 3 infoButtons with Visible = false
            }
        }
        private void createInfoButton()
        {
            Button infoButton = infoButtonCreration("infoButton");
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(infoButton);
            infoButton.Click += new EventHandler(btnInfo_Click);
        }
        private void createContractButton()
        {
            Button contractButton = contractButtonCreation("contractButton");
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(contractButton);
            contractButton.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
        }
        Button contractButtonCreation(string contract)
        {
            Button b = new Button();

            b.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 1;
            b.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
            b.Name = contract;
            b.Size = new Size(150, 80);
            b.Text = contract;
            b.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;

            return b;
        }
        Button infoButtonCreration(string info)
        {
            Button b = new Button();

            b.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 1;            
            b.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
            b.Name = info;
            b.Size = new Size(70, 80);
            b.Text = info;
            b.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;

            b.Visible = false;         //this with make the button hidden

            return b;
        }
        private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //here i need the magic, on click i need the infoButton nect to me to be visible

        }
        private void btnInfo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button b = (sender as Button);
            b.Text = "name"; //simple even when button gets visible so i can test it woeks
        }
    }
}
```

I hope i explained my needs.
Thank you very much for your support guys.
Kind Regards
 [how it should look when working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjz0l.png)

Comment: Loop through the controls and find your button or hold onto the instance.

Comment: You can just use 1 button and change its content on click instead, inside btn_Click() you check what is the content text is (or any other flag you set), if its "contractButton" then change it to "infoButton", if its "infoButton" perform the task you need...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Tag on contractButton, then when you clicked the button convert tag to button.

```
namespace DynamicButtons
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) //simple loop just to simulate the request
            {
                createContractButton();                    
            }
        }
        private Button createInfoButton()
        {
            Button infoButton = infoButtonCreration("infoButton");
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(infoButton);
            infoButton.Click += new EventHandler(btnInfo_Click);
            return infoButton;
        }
        private void createContractButton()
        {
            Button contractButton = contractButtonCreation("contractButton");
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(contractButton);
            contractButton.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);

            contractButton.Tag=createInfoButton();

        }
        Button contractButtonCreation(string contract)
        {
            Button b = new Button();

            b.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 1;
            b.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
            b.Name = contract;
            b.Size = new Size(150, 80);
            b.Text = contract;
            b.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;

            return b;
        }
        Button infoButtonCreration(string info)
        {
            Button b = new Button();

            b.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 1;
            b.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
            b.Name = info;
            b.Size = new Size(70, 80);
            b.Text = info;
            b.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;

            b.Visible = false;         //this with make the button hidden

            return b;
        }
        private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ((Button)((sender as Button)?.Tag)).Visible = true;            
        }
        private void btnInfo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button b = (sender as Button);
            b.Text = "name"; //simple even when button gets visible so i can test it woeks
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Henoc, this example works perfectly for me, and it was easy to implement to my needs. thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

When doing something like this, I prefer to create a custom class deriving from the **System.Windows.Forms.Button** class and add properties to it that help me to make subsequent calls easier.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) //simple loop just to simulate the request
        {
            createContractButton();  //will generate 3 contractButtons with Visible = true
            // createInfoButton(); - Don't do this here
        }
    }
    private Button createInfoButton()
    {
        Button infoButton = infoButtonCreration("infoButton");
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(infoButton);
        infoButton.Click += new EventHandler(btnInfo_Click);

        return infoButton;
    }
    private void createContractButton()
    {
        MyCustomButton contractButton = contractButtonCreation("contractButton");
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(contractButton);
        contractButton.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);

        // Create new infoButton here, tied directly to the ContractButton you have just created
        contractButton.InfoButton = this.createInfoButton();
    }
    MyCustomButton contractButtonCreation(string contract)
    {
        MyCustomButton b = new MyCustomButton();

        b.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 1;
        b.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
        b.Name = contract;
        b.Size = new Size(150, 80);
        b.Text = contract;
        b.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;

        return b;
    }
    Button infoButtonCreration(string info)
    {
        Button b = new Button();

        b.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 1;
        b.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
        b.Name = info;
        b.Size = new Size(70, 80);
        b.Text = info;
        b.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;

        b.Visible = false;         //this with make the button hidden

        return b;
    }
    private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //here i need the magic, on click i need the infoButton nect to me to be visible
        MyCustomButton button = sender as MyCustomButton;
        button.InfoButton.Visible = true;
    }
    private void btnInfo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = (sender as Button);
        b.Text = "name"; //simple even when button gets visible so i can test it woeks
    }
}

public class MyCustomButton : Button
{
    public Button InfoButton { get; set; }
}
```

The MyCustomButton class works exactly like a normal Button, but with the added benefit of having a nice custom property to access the InfoButton or any other property you want to add to it later.

Comment: JayV, thank you for your support, this example works as well.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you need reference for hidden buttons. If you do not want to do the buttons variables, you can add tag for contractButton  with position in flowLayoutPanel1.control. On event OnClick the contractButton get tag and add 1 and get button from flowLayoutPanel1.controls panel and change the Visible = true

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    var hiddenBtn = flowLayoutPanel1.controls[btn.Tag + 1];
    hiddenBtn.Visible = true;
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
    {
       createContractButton(i);  
       createInfoButton();  
    }
}

private void createContractButton(int i)
{
    Button contractButton = contractButtonCreation("contractButton");
    contractButton.Tag = i
    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(contractButton);
    contractButton.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
 }
```

**One note: b.Name must be unique**